# PHP Header call for internal page redirect

Tags: php, html, redirect, header

I have a contact form, and after validation is complete, I would like it to redirect to another messageSent.php file. I thought using include would work, but that just adds the whole page about the contact page.

I read to use the header() function to redirect the page. But all examples showed using a live site url location. My files are all internal and I'm testing locally.

How do I properly call the header() function to redirect to a page in my root folder?

PHP:

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
$POST = filter_post($_POST);
$invoice = array_splice($POST,3,1);
$MSG = check_empty($POST);
$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);

if(!array_filter($MSG)){
    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $MSG[] = "Invalid Email Format (test@provider.com)";
    }
    else{
        $POST['invoice'] = $invoice['invoice'];
        if(send_mail($POST)){
            include '/Users/orobosaenagbare/Dropbox/Websites/Se7en Service/messageSent.php';
        }
        else{
            $MSG[] = "Email Failed";
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The path that you send with `header('Location: path');` can be relative: `header('Location: messageSent.php');`

Comment: perfect it worked. Thanks!

Comment: but the url being something like "http://localhost:8888/contact.php" wouldn't work universally once I put this all live. Just trying to minimize and errors down the road. @Popnoodles

Comment: It's common to use a configuration file that is unique to each installation which has things like the hostname in it (which can also be recieved with `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`)

Comment: @samlev what if its a different folder/sub? eg. my login is site.com/login, but if I put Location: home then it tries to do login/home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call:

```
header('Location: relative/path/to/file.php');
```

And it should work.  Depending on the local web server and your web root directory you could use an absolute path from the web root directory by prefixing with `/`.

It's important to note that header() must be called before any output.